# Pool of dependencies rahter than one in Hystrix

Tags: hystrix, netflix, resiliency

I understand that we execute a command in hystrix against a dependency. Lets say that dependency is exposed as a web service endpoint (REST). In my case that dependency is a server farm (a pool of servers established to serve high availability). Can I pass a pool of dependencies to Hystrix rather than one? What I assume from Hystrix than that it can start invoking randomly but with the passage of time evaluates and break the circuit (if required) if ALL of them are exhausted, based on certain factors i.e.; (time out, thread pool exhaustion, error etc).